# What is the best MongoDb schema for this data

Tags: mongodb, schema, nosql

Ok, I will start to say that I am not a newbie, but I am looking for the best solution.

I have 4-way relationship, for simplicity:

```
Busines
{
 bid: unique,
 name: string
}

Client
{
 cid: unique,
 name: string
}

Product
{
 pid: unique,
 name: string
}

Order
{
 oid: unique,
 bid: FK,
 cid: FK,
 pid: FK
}
```

What would be the BEST way to build this in Mongo?

Pay attention, that the same client CAN be in many businesses and the same Product too.

So some times I will need to make selection by ALL orders of the Client, and have the data grouped by business and other time by product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your comment:

> I agree but the problem is in the speed and the Sharding/Replication of MongoDB is better then MySQL for example... And I am going to have lot's of the small Order elements (In millions) and here the RDBS will have it's disadvantage... :(

I believe you are looking at this wrong. MongoDB will ONLY be faster than a RDBMS if it fits your scenario in such a manner to make it faster.

Millions of rows is not even shard worthy in most databases and even a commodity server can handle at least a couple of terabytes of information. Sharding comes from a need to increase your write capacity, just like it does in RDBMS technologies, not from the size of your data necessarily.

However as to answer the schema question, I would leave it as it is at the moment except I would remove orders and replace that inside of a client:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    name: 'sammaye',
    orders: [
        {oid:{},bid:{},cid:{},pid:{}},
        { //etc }
    ]
}
```

It is a small and meger object which should not cause too many problems and it won't be increasing by like 100 every day so it shouldn't cause heavy and immediate fragmentation.

If you find it does cause fragmentation on your traffic and order rate you could always just use power of 2 sizes allocation ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/ ) to help out, however I should warn this is actually less performant in the short term so do not apply this option without needing it.

That is, with the information you have given us. how I would design that schema.

Comment: 1st of all I agree with your comment above, about the size of information, and I too had databases with, well maybe not terabytes but a gigabytes, but my problem is not in size, it's in the amount of small operations (The orders). And here NoSQL have a clear advantage over SQL. I do like your approach of embedding the order to the client... I will have to play with it, though.

Comment: @AlexFrenkel Yes if you are looking at a lot of operations then it could be more performant, it just sounded like you based your need for sharding on the data size that's all :)

Comment: No, sorry... was my mistake :) The data size is actually really small this time... First time for me, that I dont anticipate my database to be over 1GB Disk space...

Answer (score 0):

To give an alternative approach, you could keep `Clients` as a separate collection, and embed (at least some of) the `Product` information in the `Order`.

It's normally important to know what the customer ordered (and the price they paid, currency etc) at the point in time that the order was taken.  You'd still hold a reference to the product, but it would mean you could view an historical order and actually see what they customer bought at the time. Product details legitimately change over time.

This would still mean fast reads; I'm assuming the business collection would be much smaller than the clients, so maybe something you could deal with at an application level (i.e. caching the businesses so you're not doing a look up each on on the db)

I appreciate much of the info i'm talking about is not currently in the Product docs, but maybe something to think about.

There is of course a document size limit, and if you were denormalising the product info (or some of it) and a single customer could place orders for many businesses you need to check you have scope to hold this information in the customer collection - but that's dependant on number of orders and the size of them etc.

Anyway, already some good answers dealing with the technicalities of performance etc, just thought I'd offer a different opinion.